# Tinymce text editor doesn't work on bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I'm using tinymce text editor in my project it's working properly in the main window but when i try to load bootstrap modal the simple textarea appears and there's no Tinymce's option.
Here's my site and login info: hmodelschool.co.nf,  email: admin@example.com pass: 1234
In the news section you'll see the tinymce option comes properly. but when i try to edit with bootstrap modal tinymce's option doesn't come. wht to do.
 Here my code i'm using. 
in include.top.php
i'm loading tinymce from cdn.

```
  <!--tinymce text editor-->
  <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 300,
  theme: 'modern',
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor 
    pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu   
    directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern 
     imagetools'
  ],
  toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | 
   alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist 
   outdent indent | link image',
  toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
  image_advtab: true,
  });</script>
```

in main page news.php
i'm calling it with:

```
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
    <?php  echo get_phrase('news');?></label> <div class="col-sm-5"> 
   <div class="box closable-chat-box"> <div class="box-content padded"> 
   <div class="chat-message-box"> <textarea name="news" id="ttt" 
    rows="5" placeholder="<?php echo get_phrase('add_news');?>" 
   class="form-control"></textarea> </div>   
  </div> 
   </div> 
  </div>
  </div>
```

and also in modal_edit_news.php
 i'm calling it with:

```
   <div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
    <?php  echo get_phrase('news');?></label> <div class="col-sm-5"> 
   <div class="box closable-chat-box"> <div class="box-content padded"> 
   <div class="chat-message-box"> <textarea name="news" id="ttt" 
    rows="5" placeholder="<?php echo get_phrase('add_news');?>" 
   class="form-control"></textarea> </div>   
  </div> 
   </div> 
  </div>
  </div>
```

And the tinymce doesn't just work on bootstrap modal.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had encountered a similar issue when loading a modal over an AJAX request. The workaround is to initialize the TinyMCE editor on loading the modal.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    height: 300,
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor 
      pagebreak',
      'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
      'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu   
      directionality',
      'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern 
       imagetools'
    ],
    toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | 
     alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist 
     outdent indent | link image',
    toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
    image_advtab: true,
  });
})
```

Comment: Pls, tell a bit more how and where i should apply ur code? thanks for reply.

Comment: @Nirob put your javascript code into a .js file, and load it from your page, the same way you did with the tinymce.min.js file.

Comment: sorry, still no luck.