# TinyMCE, Bootstrap Modal & URL Parameter: wp is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap 5 & WordPress 6.2

I'm building out a WordPress plugin. I've got a Dashboard and an All Content page.

The Dashboard page lists the most recently created content; each entry in the list has an Edit link that users can click to take them to the All Content page that shows a Bootstrap Modal with the content's data available to edit.

The Edit link on the Dashboard is something like this:

- admin.php?page=my-plugin-all-content&the_content=65

65 is the content ID in the database and the my-plugin-all-content.php page is waiting for $_GET['the_content'] to be available and retrieves the content's data from the database based on the ID.

The function that retrieves the data from the database adds javascript to the output to initialiaze tinymce:

```
$sections_scripts.= '<script>
                            wp.editor.initialize(\'my_plugin_section_'.$section_count.'_text\',{
                                tinymce: {
                                  wpautop: true,
                                  plugins : \'charmap colorpicker compat3x directionality fullscreen hr lists media paste tabfocus textcolor wordpress wpautoresize wpdialogs wpeditimage wpemoji wpgallery wplink wptextpattern wpview\',
                                  toolbar1: \'bold italic underline strikethrough | bullist numlist | blockquote hr wp_more | alignleft aligncenter alignright | link unlink | fullscreen | wp_adv\',
                                  toolbar2: \'formatselect alignjustify forecolor | pastetext removeformat charmap | outdent indent | undo redo | wp_help\',
                                  valid_elements: \'*\',
                                  verify_html: false
                                },
                                quicktags: true,
                                mediaButtons: true,
                              });</script>';
```

The $sections_scripts variable, now populated with all the initializer scripts for however many textareas there are, is put at the bottom of the Bootstrap Modal so the textareas have time to create.

That all works fine; all the fields in the Bootstrap Modal populate with the correct data, etc.

What does NOT work is the textarea in the Bootstrap Modal does not change into a wp_editor (tinymce) when initialized; it gives me a "wp is not defined" error (referencing the wp.editor.initialize line).

If I go directly to admin.php?page=my-plugin-all-content and click any of the Edit links for the content listed there, the Bootstrap Modal displays perfectly via jQuery; the correct wp_editors are initialized with jQuery POST instead of the $_GET variable.

So it seems the use of $_GET and wp.editor.initialize don't want to work?

Any ideas? Happy to try to explain this better or post more of the code, if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question after seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621276/tinymce-text-editor-doesnt-work-on-bootstrap-modal-window) and some additional tinkering.

I was using javascript to show the Bootstrap Modal after the data populated from the $_GET variable.

Instead of putting the $sections_scripts in the Modal itself, I ended up putting it in some jQuery after the javascript for showing the Modal:

```
<?php
echo '<script>
var content_modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("my_plugin_edit_box"), {});
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  content_modal.show();}</script>
  <script>
  jQuery("#my_plugin_edit_box").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
  '.$sections_scripts.'
  });
  </script>';
?>
```